# Zend model declaration not compatible with abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework

Even that my system is still functioning properly my error-log is suddenly overflowding with errors like these:

```
2012-07-20T02:53:25+00:00 WARN (4): [2048] Declaration of User_Model_User::getParent() should be compatible with Core_Model_Item_Abstract::getParent($recurseType = NULL) ([…]/application/modules/User/Model/User.php) [20]
Error Code: 1b29e1
Stack trace:
#0 […]/application/libraries/Engine/Loader.php(103): include_once('/dana/data/www.altandetlige.dk/d...')
#1 (unknown file)(0): Engine_Loader::autoload('User_Model_User')
#2 (unknown file)(0): spl_autoload_call('User_Model_User')
#3 […]/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Table/Rowset/Abstract.php(114): class_exists('User_Model_User')
#4 […]/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1340): Zend_Db_Table_Rowset_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#5 […]/application/libraries/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1290): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll('((`engine4_users`.`user_id` = 1)...')
#6 […]/application/modules/User/Api/Core.php(334): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->find(1)
#7 […]/application/modules/User/Api/Core.php(167): User_Api_Core->_getUser(1)
#8 […]/application/modules/User/Bootstrap.php(34): User_Api_Core->getViewer()
#9 […]/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(783): User_Bootstrap->__construct(Core_Bootstrap)
#10 […]/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(256): Core_Bootstrap->_initModules()
#11 […]/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(207): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->_executeResource('modules')
#12 […]/application/libraries/Engine/Application/Bootstrap/Abstract.php(150): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->_bootstrap()
#13 […]/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(149): Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract->bootstrap()
#14 […]/application/index.php(193): Engine_Application->bootstrap()
#15 […]/index.php(24): include('/dana/data/www.altandetlige.dk/d...')
#16 {main}
```

All Models using the Core_Model_Item_Abstract will produce the exact same error.

The strange thing is that the error only show on the production server (running PHP 5.4.3) and not on the development setup (running PHP 5.2.11).

From the error it is clear that the Core_Model_Item_Abstract do not seem to get the expected parameters, but no changes have been make to the Core_Model_Item_Abstract and if it was the case it would properly show in both production and development.

**[EDIT]**

The parent class in `Core_Model_Item_Abstract` looks like this. For me it seems like the code is already taking into account that `$recurseType` is not set:

```
public function getParent($recurseType = null) {
    if( empty($recurseType) ) $recurseType = null; // Parent and owner are same
    if( !empty($this->_parent_is_owner) ) { 
        return $this->getOwner($recurseType); 
    }
}
```

Anybody have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Very likely you are doing something that was acceptable in php 5.2 days but now causes a warning. Post the code for User_Model_User so we can compare to your warning and to your abstract. Maybe someone can pin it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
class User_Model_User {
    function getParent() {
    ...
```

to

```
class User_Model_User {
    function getParent($recurseType = NULL) {
    ...
```

and the problem should go away. This change will not break anything, but will only quiet your logs.

Or you could do this:

```
abstract class Core_Model_Item_Abstract 
{
  public function getParent(/*$recurseType = NULL*/)
  {
      $recurseType = NULL; # forcing to null as no one is passing this parameter
      ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I have 100+ models the and getChildren etc. also are effected is it posible to do the trick in the Core_Model_Item_Abstract instead?

Comment: Review the `Core_Model_Item_Abstract` class, and if `$recurseType` isn't mentioned anywhere in the function, then you can safely remove it from the function signature. You could also remove it if you know that you're classes are the only classes that will subclass this class. If you do, then simply add `$recurseType = NULL;` as the first line of the function.

Comment: The parent class in Core_Model_Item_Abstract looks like this. For me it seems like the code is already taking into account that $recurseType is not set:
  
`public function getParent($recurseType = null)
      {
    if( empty($recurseType) ) $recurseType = null;

    // Parent and owner are same
    if( !empty($this->_parent_is_owner) ) {
      return $this->getOwner($recurseType);
    }
    .....`

Comment: Again, if you are certain no other code will subclass `Core_Model_Item_Abstract` with a function that will be called with a `$recurseType` parameter, you could remove parameter from the function signature. See above

Answer (score 0):

In your parent class you can do if you want to avoid changing all the subclasses.

```
abstract class Core_Model_Item_Abstract 
{
  public function getParent()
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: I am not following you here. The Core_Model_Item_Abstract already have a getParent function?

Comment: @PeterJensen simply rename ur getParent($recurseType = null) to getParent();

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5.4, this happens if the child class overrides a method from the parent class and has a different signature from the parent class.

If you disable displaying errors for E_STRICT, it will get resolved.